# ColdFusion Server slow connection to dedicated database server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, coldfusion

We had our database and web server on the same box. For performance reasons, we are now off loading the database to a dedicated server. When updating the CFDSNs to the new server, the verification takes a long time (~30s) but it will connect and it will authenticate.

- Both servers are windows 2008 r2
- Both servers are in the same data center
- The DB server is running MySQL
- The DB server is outfitted with SSD drives
- We've tried ODBC (running through SeeFusion) and MySQL 4/5 options in CF Admin

Any suggestions on what we can do to speed up the connection? It is affecting the page load times of our server.

Comment: What do you get if you do a tracert from the CF server to the DB server? Are you using a host name or IP address? If the former, for the purposes of testing: try an IP address to see if there's any difference. Can you enable any logging on the MySQL end to see if it's taking 30sec to get the request, or 30sec to process the request, etc? As well as being in the same data centre, are they also on the same network segment?

Comment: @AdamCameron tracert To answer your questions: tracert was 4 hops. I'm using IP address in the connection string. Logging did not reveal any issues that I could tell. I'm not sure how to tell about the network segment. The first 2 octets are the same if that helps. I did find this SQ question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021745/how-to-determine-whether-two-ip-addresses-belong-to-the-same-network-segment but that answer is beyond my skill sets.

Comment: Turns out there were a couple of server configuration issues that we had to iron out. 
1) the server DNS wasn't setup correctly. 
2) The hardware firewall wasn't properly setup and as a result of that, the server was being bombarded by failed loading attempts, literally hundreds in a matter of minutes. We believe it was this that was really slowing down CF from authenticating the DSN. After correcting this issue is when we saw CF authenticating quickly. Item 1 just prevented us from accessing the internet.

Comment: OK, pls write up an answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were a couple of server configuration issues that we had to iron out.

1. The server's DNS wasn't setup correctly. This just prevented us from accessing the internet and probably had no bearing on the slow authentication.
2. The hardware firewall wasn't properly setup either and as a result of that, the server was being bombarded by failed loading attempts, literally hundreds in a matter of minutes. We believe it was this that was really slowing down CF from authenticating the DSN. After correcting this issue is when we saw CF authenticating quickly.